# how to get component of JSON String which returns by webservice request

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am using angular2 typeScript to get json returned from webservice.I can get the value from WebService by calling get but I can not get component of JSON.For instance I want to get status of the returned JSON. I can get whole JSON but not the exact status of JSON.
You can see the sample code and the JSON that returned by webservice below.

Regards
Alper

Sample Code :

```
this.http.get(this.webServiceUrlGet)
  .subscribe(
    function (data) {
      this.tradeShows = JSON.stringify(data);
      console.log(this.tradeShows);

    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

    JSON : 
   "_body":"{\n  \"args\": {}, \n  \"headers\": {\n    \"Accept\":      \"application/json, text/plain, */*\", \n    \"Accept-Encoding\": \"gzip, deflate, sdch, br\", \n    \"Accept-Language\": \"tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\", \n    \"Connect-Time\": \"0\", \n    \"Connection\": \"close\", \n    \"Host\": \"httpbin.org\", \n    \"Origin\": \"http://localhost:3000\", \n    \"Referer\": \"http://localhost:3000/navigation\", \n    \"Total-Route-Time\": \"0\", \n    \"User-Agent\": \"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36\", \n    \"Via\": \"1.1 vegur\", \n    \"X-Request-Id\": \"db6c93bd-99dd-4410-a709-5bc2dd4150fb\"\n  }, \n  \"origin\": \"212.175.18.38\", \n  \"url\": \"https://httpbin.org/get\"\n}\n","status":200,"ok":true,"statusText":"OK","headers":{"Content-Type":["application/json"]},"type":2,"url":"https://httpbin.org/get"}
```

Comment: why don't you use `console.log(this.tradeShows.status);`

Comment: I tried it before but it tells me undefined sachilla.

Comment: You need to `JSON.parse(response)`.i.e. `data` in your case

Comment: "I want to get status of the returned JSON" You mean the http status code ?

Comment: yea n00dl3.I just get the status with data.status.But I wonder how i can get an attribute of JSON. It gives me lots of errros when I user JSON.parse(response). Do you think I have to map it to an object or is there any way to get attribute of a json such like this.tradeShows.userId of a userId of an user. cheers

Comment: You cannot `JSON.parse(response)`, response is a JS object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

`this.tradeShows = data.json();`

The object you get back from an HTTP call when you subscribe is a `Response` object which has information about all aspects of the HTTP call including headers, body, etc. The json() method automatically takes the body field and turns it into an object you can use.

By the way, `JSON.stringify()` takes an object and converts it into a string. If you were going to do manual JSON parsing you would need to use `JSON.parse()`.

If you want to get the HTTP status code sent back you can access that on the status property of the response: `data.status`

Comment: he also wants the http status according to what I understand.

Comment: Thank you Jesse.As you told me data.json().userId solved my problem. Cheers

Comment: np, I'm glad that it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the status **AND** the json you can do this :

```
this.http.get(this.webServiceUrlGet)
  .map(resp=>[resp.status,resp.json()])
  .subscribe(([status,data]) => {
      this.tradeShows = data;
      this.status = status;
      console.log(this.tradeShows,this.status);
    },
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
```

you need to call `resp.json()` because what is sent by the Http service is a [`Response` object](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html)

Comment: Why would you stringify the result?

Comment: that's an artefact from the OP, I deleted

Answer (score -1):

While using typescript you need map the value and subscribe it in component page for example

**Service call to api**

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from "@angular/http";
constructor(
        private authHttp: Http) {}
let url= `this.webServiceUrlGet`;
      let params = new URLSearchParams;
      params.append('id', id);
     return this.authHttp.post( url,  { headers:headers,  search:params })
    .map( res =>  res.json());
```

**Component**

```
this.service.get(this.id)
                .subscribe(
                res => this.item= res,
                error => this.errorMessage = error
                );
```

Comment: That's not related to typescript but to angular `Http` service. Why surround `this.webServiceUrlGet` with backticks ? and why not using OP code as base (ie: `Http`  instead of the `authHttp` service) ?

Comment: That's my 'authHttp' object assigned from Http

Comment: Hello Venkateswaran I need a solution in typeScript bro

Comment: we should assign the result to an Observable object from the service .
 '.subscribe' is the function that actually executes the observable. It takes three callback parameters as follow (success,failure,complete). We can convert the object in json format either service or Component.

Comment: Backticks are purely a template string, there is no inherent language that is used between backticks